# Parallel.ForEach Error

Tags: c#, parallel.foreach

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The context cannot be used while the model is
>   being created. This exception may be thrown if the context is used
>   inside the OnModelCreating method or if the same context instance is
>   accessed by multiple threads concurrently. Note that instance members
>   of DbContext and related classes are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

```
IQueryable<VMPARForms> TempfilteredMember = filteredMember;                      

IQueryable<clsPARForms> parformslist = dbcontext.PARForms;

Parallel.ForEach(TempfilteredMember.Where(c => c.PARStatus == 21), item =>
{
    var list = parformslist.Where(x => x.CaseNumber == item.CaseNumber && x.PARID != item.PARID).FirstOrDefault();

    if (list != null)
    {
        item.PARStatus = list.PARStatus;
    }

});
```

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: when i am using foreach() it will take long time around 4 min because i have 1lack records so by using  parallel.foreach() to  reduce execution time

Comment: `if the same context instance is accessed by multiple threads concurrently.` You are doing that. You can't do it. Don't use `Parallel.ForEach`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that you are trying to create multiple objects of the EF Context. The documentation said that

> The ObjectContext class is not thread safe. The integrity of data objects in an ObjectContext cannot be ensured in multithreaded scenarios.
>   [The ObjectContext class is not thread safe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.aspx)
>
> The context is not thread safe. You can still create a multithreaded application as long as an instance of the same entity class is not tracked by multiple contexts at the same time. [EF Multithreading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj729737(v=vs.113).aspx)

Depending on your application, you could materialize your data by using the `ToList()` , and filter it on demand, or try to change the logic of your query.